# Visual Basic ActiveX control can't access properties and methods at run time

Tags: activex

I have a simple ActiveX control that have 4 properties and 8 methods Set and Get, the problem is that i can't access them at runtime , at desin time they works fine
below is the error message that occur when i lanch the programm in visual basic
and Dispatch map  with file.idl of my ActiveX control.
In Visual C++ i have a message "member not found" when a access the propertys or methods.
Is anyone can help me with this problem.
Thanks in advance.

**An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
Additional information: Catastrophic failure (exception HRESULT: 0x8000FFFF (E_UNEXPECTED))**

CSliderCtrl1.cpp File has dispatch map

BEGIN_DISPATCH_MAP(CSliderCtrl1, COleControl)
    DISP_PROPERTY_EX_ID(CSliderCtrl1, "backgroundColor", 1, GetbackgroundColor, SetbackgroundColor, VT_I4)
    DISP_PROPERTY_EX_ID(CSliderCtrl1, "backColor", 2, GetbackColor, SetbackColor, VT_I4)
    DISP_PROPERTY_EX_ID(CSliderCtrl1, "foreColor", 3, GetforeColor, SetforeColor, VT_I4)
    DISP_PROPERTY_EX_ID(CSliderCtrl1, "positionBar", 4, GetpositionBar, SetpositionBar, VT_I4)
END_DISPATCH_MAP()

Slider.idl File

## include

## include

[ uuid(F9248E73-F5AD-43B1-815B-91817E91B537), version(1.0), control ]
library SliderLib
{
    importlib(STDOLE_TLB);

```
//  Primary dispatch interface for CSliderCtrl1
[ uuid(093C2CB6-C812-4B91-84CB-1C508439DBFD) ]
dispinterface _DSlider 
{
    properties:
        [id(1)] COLORREF backgroundColor;
        [id(2)] COLORREF backColor;
        [id(3)] COLORREF foreColor;
        [id(4)] unsigned long positionBar;
    methods:
        [id(5)] COLORREF GetbackgroundColor();
        [id(6)] void SetbackgroundColor([in] COLORREF color );
        [id(7)] COLORREF GetbackColor();
        [id(8)] void SetbackColor([in] COLORREF color);
        [id(9)] COLORREF GetforeColor();
        [id(10)] void SetforeColor([in] COLORREF color);
        [id(11)] unsigned long GetpositionBar();
        [id(12)] void SetpositionBar([in] unsigned long position);


};

//  Event dispatch interface for CSliderCtrl1

[ uuid(9113AA84-629F-4C34-88A3-EBFFF0F94B2E) ]
dispinterface _DSliderEvents
{
    properties:
        //  Event interface has no properties

    methods:
};

//  Class information for CSliderCtrl1
[ uuid(FA933E84-1B30-4283-9A2A-9CC1E8D99408), control ]
coclass Slider
{
    [default] dispinterface _DSlider;
    [default, source] dispinterface _DSliderEvents;
};
```

};

Comment: Hi there! I think the code in your question could use some formatting, it's barely readable as it is.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i found the way, the code in Visual Basic must be

Dim slider As New Object

slider = AxSlider1.**GetOcx**

slider.SetbackgroundColor(100000)

```
BEGIN_DISPATCH_MAP(CSliderCtrl1, COleControl)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CSliderCtrl1, "GetbackgroundColor",1, GetbackgroundColor,VT_UI4,VTS_NONE)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CSliderCtrl1, "SetbackgroundColor",2, SetbackgroundColor, VT_EMPTY,VTS_UI4 )
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CSliderCtrl1, "GetbackColor",3, GetbackColor, VT_UI4, VTS_NONE)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CSliderCtrl1, "SetbackColor", 4,SetbackColor, VT_EMPTY, VTS_UI4)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CSliderCtrl1, "GetforeColor",5, GetforeColor,VT_UI4, VTS_NONE)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CSliderCtrl1, "SetforeColor", 6,SetforeColor, VT_EMPTY, VTS_UI4)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CSliderCtrl1, "GetPositionBar",7, GetPositionBar,VT_UI4, VTS_NONE)
    DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CSliderCtrl1, "SetPositionBar", 8,SetPositionBar, VT_EMPTY, VTS_UI4)
 DISP_PROPERTY_EX_ID(CSliderCtrl1, "backgroundColor", dispidBackgroundColor, GetbackgroundColor, SetbackgroundColor, VT_UI4)
 DISP_PROPERTY_EX_ID(CSliderCtrl1, "backColor", dispidBackColor, GetbackColor, SetbackColor, VT_UI4)
 DISP_PROPERTY_EX_ID(CSliderCtrl1, "foreColor", dispidForeColor, GetforeColor, SetforeColor, VT_UI4)
 DISP_PROPERTY_EX_ID(CSliderCtrl1, "PositionBar", dispidPositionBar, GetPositionBar, SetPositionBar, VT_UI4)
END_DISPATCH_MAP()
```